# Как написать макрос в ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, c, ubuntu

У меня имеется 3 `.cpp` файла, я бы хотел иметь макрос, который отдельно делает сборку каждого файла.
Например, main1.cpp, main2.cpp, main3.cpp  После вызова макроса я бы хотел иметь 3 разных исполняемых файла. Что для этого нужно?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make

Comment: например: `$ make main1`